# How to load EMNIST data to Tensorflow

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In all the tutorials i've seen for tensorflow, they've used the MNIST dataset, i've understood the modelling but how do i load this dataset into tensorflow?
https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/emnist-dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EMNIST dataset](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/emnist-dataset) uses the same binary format as the original [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). Therefore you can take the input pipeline code from any tutorial that uses the original MNIST dataset, and point it at the set of files you get from downloading the EMNIST dataset to train on that dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the EMNIST data file in Matlab format with scipy.io.loadmat(). The array has to be rotated after loading. There is a Jupyter Notebook on GitHub which does [EMNIST Digits classification](https://github.com/j05t/emnist/blob/master/emnist.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EMNIST package that can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/emnist/

To load the dataset you first need to decide which of the six different datasets you would like to work with. Details in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05373v1.pdf

Let's say we want to use the byclass dataset:

```
from emnist import extract_training_samples, extract_test_samples
x_train, y_train = extract_training_samples('byclass')
x_test, y_test = extract_test_samples('byclass')
```