# Using Tensorflow Dataset in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The Tensorflow package `tensorflow-datasets` has an extensive set of datasets.

I could do `tfds.list_builders()` to see the entire list of datasets, and then use one of them like:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
emnist_train = tfds.load(name="emnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN, as_supervised=True)
emnist_test  = tfds.load(name="emnist", split=tfds.Split.TEST,  as_supervised=True)
```

How do I use `emnist_train` and `emnist_test` which was imported with `tfds.load` with keras `load_data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your data like this

```
emnist_train = tfds.load(name="emnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN, batch_size=-1 ) 
emnist_test = tfds.load(name="emnist", split=tfds.Split.TEST, batch_size=-1)

emnist_train = tfds.as_numpy(emnist_train) 
emnist_test = tfds.as_numpy(emnist_test)

x_train, y_train = emnist_train["image"], emnist_train["label"] 
x_test, y_test = emnist_test["image"], emnist_test["label"]
```

Comment: It works with `mnist` dataset, but not with `emnist` dataset. The idea is to be able to utilize any of the datasets downloaded with `tensorflow_datasets` with keras `load_data()`

Comment: Check this out,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/47854014/11701676

Comment: I already have `emnist` dataset in tensorflow. I want to be able to use it with keras.

Comment: @Saurabh I have updated my answer, this worked for me